# SQL Server LIKE search with [ ] not matching as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I'm trying to search the contents of a `text` column in a SQL Server DB.  I do not have the ability to add a fulltext index to the column, so I'm trying to do so in a query:

```
SELECT t.DateBegin, t.Action, t.Detail, t.Status, t.ErrorText, 
  CASE WHEN t.ErrorText LIKE '%[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664]%' THEN 'IBM'
   WHEN t.ErrorText LIKE '%WebApplicationContainerServer%' THEN 'WACS'
  ELSE '' END AS ErrorType
FROM (
SELECT a.DateBegin, a.Action, a.Detail, a.Status,  
CONVERT(varchar(max), 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(a.ExtInfo AS varchar(max)), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
) as ErrorText
FROM bi4infoburst.dbo.IBT_RTS_ACTION a
WHERE a.DateBegin >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
  AND a.Status = 5
) t
ORDER BY t.DateBegin
```

My thought here is that if I converted it to a `varchar` then I could use the LIKE operator.  But when I run this query, it always matches the first case regardless of what text or pattern I put in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with [character escaping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Square brackets have to be handled properly because otherwise are interpreted as special chars like `%` is; using square brackets you match any of the char inside the brackets and that's why the first `CASE` always matches.

The solution is to to declare an escape character in the statement to escape the brackets.

If used in a `WHERE` clause the syntax would be as follows:

```
WHERE t.ErrorText LIKE '%![IBM!]![CLI Driver!]![DB2/LINUXX8664!]%' ESCAPE '!'
```

I don't know if is possible and how to use it in a `CASE` statement...

Comment: That looks like the issue.  I changed the title of the question to be more appropriate.